# problem installing adhoc app with itunes 9.2

Tags: iphone, itunes, adhoc

I just installed itunes 9.2. Then tried doing something I've done thousands of times before: installing an add hoc build. I deleted the old version of the app and dragged the new version onto the app section of itunes. I get a message that the profile with the same name already exists (I select replace). Nothing happens- the app is not installed and does not show up in the app list.

Any ideas? The only difference is iTunes 9.2

Answer (score 0):

https://devforums.apple.com/message/242443#242443

vChav wrote:

> Ok, after removing all traces of the
>   app from iTunes and rebuilding it
>   worked. Here's exactly what I did:
>
> 1) Make a new folder called Payload 2)
>   Copy the build into Payload 3) Zip
>   Payload in the Finder 4) Rename the
>   zipped file MyApp.ipa 5) Drag the .ipa
>   file into iTunes 6) Sync the device
>
> Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem as well. The solution was to package the app as an .IPA file using Xcode. The process is detailed here:

[A better way to share ad hoc builds](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/23/devsugar-a-better-way-to-share-ad-hoc-builds/)